# Direct proof of the null operator of a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space over the field of complex numbers with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ while $A: H\rightarrow H$ is an operator. I can prove
$$(x,Ax)=0,\,\forall x\in H\implies A=0$$
by turning this problem into a linear algebra/matrix problem through using the coordinate of an orthonormal basis.

Is there a more direct way without resorting to using the coordinate of an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Are you sure about this result, in this generality? Consider $H=\mathbb{C}^2$, and $A(x_1, x_2)=(-x_2, x_1)$. I think that $(x, Ax)=0$ for all $x$, but $A$ is nonzero

Comment: @NicolásVilches $(x,Ax)$ is not $0$ in your example.

Comment: Oh, I see! I was really confused hahaha, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an idea! First, expand $((x+y), A(x+y))=0$ to get that
$$ \forall x, y \in H, \quad (x, Ay)+(y, Ax)=0. $$
Now, given $x, y \in H$, we apply that identity to $x, y$ and to $x, iy$ to get
$$ (x, Ay)+(y, Ax)=0, \quad (x, A(iy))+(iy, Ax)=0. $$
The last one implies that $-i(x, Ay)+i(y, Ax)=0$, or $-(x, Ay)+(y, Ax)=0$. Therefore, we get that $(y, Ax)=0$ for all $x, y \in H$, which implies that $Ax=0$ for all $x \in H$.

Comment: Oh, darn. I got the two equations separately but I did not go on to the last step of summation and subtraction...